# Scalar SQL function for checking if input value is integer

Tags: sql, function

Scalar SQL function for checking if input value is integer number or not. If not then throw error. Help me on this.

Comment: Please tag it with a specific database.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this in SQL I believe it works for you.

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(100) = '1.5'
IF ISNUMERIC(@Value) = 0
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Value must be integer or decimal',16,1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Value
END
```

Result

1. Integer
   [image]
2. Decimal
   [image]
3. String -> Error occurred in string.
   [image]

Just add the above logic into your script it's work.

Note: **In this, you can handle decimals and integers.**

Please check this updated for you

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Numeric_validation] 
(
    @P_InputValues NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    IF @P_InputValues LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    BEGIN 
        RETURN CAST('Value must be integer' AS INT);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Value = @P_InputValues
    END
RETURN   @Value;
END
SELECT [dbo].[Numeric_validation] ('10')
SELECT [dbo].[Numeric_validation] ('10.50')
SELECT [dbo].[Numeric_validation] ('TEST')
```

Comment: the fucntion will check if input value is integer or not ..if not then it will throw error. ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Numeric_validation] ( @P_InputValues NVARCHAR(MAX) ) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) BEGIN

RETURN NULL; END GO i have to put the logic within this

Comment: Okay, I'll be adding it.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Hi @MdMuntazim, please check the answer I've updated the code.

Comment: appreciate it. thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

the function will check if the input value is an integer or not ..if not then it will throw an error.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Numeric_validation] 
(
    @P_InputValues NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN

RETURN   NULL;
END
GO
```

I have to put the logic within this